# Can't load any data in backend

Tags: uicomponent, ajax, magento2.2.4, json

I've a (random ?) `<pre>` added in the end of the default json rendering content in backend (for users, products...).

I'm sure I didn't touch anything from this part of the website, any ideas ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the index.php file of your root. Generally, We add error report code there and forget about the code. So Please check the file.

Comment: Didn't touch this file either.

Answer (score 0):

Try using grep command to find the actual culprit eg.
grep -rnw "" first in app/code then in vendor maybe somewhere the logging is left.
Or try to find the files that have recently changed with : it will list the files changed in last 2 days
`find -mtime -2`